# What sort does Java Collections.sort(nodes) use?

Tags: java, collections, sorting, time-complexity, mergesort

I think it is MergeSort, which is O(n log n).

However, the following output disagrees:

```
-1,0000000099000391,0000000099000427
1,0000000099000427,0000000099000346
5,0000000099000391,0000000099000346
1,0000000099000427,0000000099000345
5,0000000099000391,0000000099000345
1,0000000099000346,0000000099000345
```

I am sorting a nodelist of 4 nodes by sequence number, and the sort is doing 6 comparisons.
I am puzzled because 6 > (4 log(4)). Can someone explain this to me?

[P.S. It is mergesort, but I still don't understand my results.](http://www.uni-ulm.de/admin/doku/jdk1.5/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator))

Thanks for the answers everyone.  Thank you Tom for correcting my math.

Comment: (Collections.sort in JDK7 should do few comparisons for partially sorted data. Josh Bloch has ported Python's Tim sort (a version of merge sort).)

Comment: If it were log base 2 (notation??), 4 log[2] 4 = 4 log[2](2^2) = 4.2 log[2] 2 = 4.2.1 = 8. (If I remember by sixth form maths correctly.) But, yes, there's a constant there.

Comment: so I guess JDK7 uses timsort by default?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

O(n log n) doesn't mean that the number of comparisons will be equal to or less than n log n, just that the time taken will **scale** proportionally to n log n. Try doing tests with 8 nodes, or 16 nodes, or 32 nodes, and checking out the timing.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I was assuming that it was number of comparisons.  My mistake.  Thanks!

Comment: That's a pretty small number of comparisons, you could comfortably multiply those by 1000 for better results.

Comment: True, but his example was with 4 initially :)

Answer (score 24):

You sorted four nodes, so you didn't get merge sort; sort switched to insertion sort.

Per the Wikipedia article on [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Comparison_with_other_sort_algorithms) (emphasis added):

> In [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_platform), the [Arrays.sort()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-java.lang.Object:A-) methods use merge sort or a tuned quicksort depending on the datatypes and for implementation efficiency **switch to [insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) when fewer than seven array elements are being sorted**.

`Arrays.sort` is used indirectly by the collections classes.

Starting with Java 7, the Oracle implementation of Java switched to use the [timsort](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Objects/listsort.txt) algorithm used by Python: [JDK-6804124](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6804124).

(The timsort monograph, linked above, is well worth reading.)

Comment: Also mentioned in the OpenJDK Forum: Core Libraries Round Table last thursday. http://mediacast.sun.com/users/robilad/media/openjdk-core-libraries-roundup.mp3 [MP3!]

Comment: Quicksort beats merge sort. Java uses quicksort as sorting algorithm.

Comment: The constants on quicksort is really small, because it s in place. Timsort, is a hybrid of merge sort and insertion sort, which uses insertion sort at merge stage, doesnt gain too much for this. The constant is still to high compared to quicksort.

Answer (score 3):

An algorithm A(n) that processes an amount of data n is in O(f(n)), for some function f, if there exist two strictly positive constants C_inf and C_sup such that:

C_inf . f(n) < ExpectedValue(OperationCount(A(n))) < C_sup . f(n)

Two things to note:

- The actual constants C could be anything, and *do* depend on the relative costs of operations (depending on the language, the VM, the architecture, or your actual definition of an operation). On some platforms, for instance, + and * have the same cost, on some other the later is an order of magnitude slower.
- The quantity ascribed as "in O(f(n))" is an *expected* operation count, based on some probably arbitrary model of the data you are dealing with. For instance, if your data is almost completely sorted, a merge-sort algorithm is going to be mostly O(n), not O(n . Log(n)).

Comment: For an arbitrary sized n-bit integer, + will typically be O(n) and * IIRC O(n log n). There are "fun" things you can do to algorithms to just use huge integers and relatively few (big-O) operations.

Comment: Quicksort is the canonical example of an algorithm which is mostly O(n log n), but can go O(n^2) (for instance sorted input with first element as pivot).

Comment: Yes... for all those complexity estimation tasks, the devil is in the model. For it to be any use, you generally also have to take into account the worst-case complexity, not just the expected cost. And it's often a b**ch to find the worst-case...

Answer (score 2):

I've written some stuff you may be interested in about the Java sort algorithm and taken [some performance measurements of Collections.sort()](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/collections/sorting_java_algorithm_performance_2.shtml). The algorithm at present is a **mergesort with an insertion sort** once you get down to a certain size of sublists (**N.B. this algorithm is very probably going to change in Java 7**).

You should really take the Big O notation as an indication of how the algorithm will scale overall; for a particular sort, the precise time will deviate from the time predicted by this calculation (as you'll see on my graph, the two sort algorithms that are combined each have different performance characteristics, and so the overall time for a sort is a bit more complex).

That said, as a rough guide, for every time you double the number of elements, if you multiply the expected time by 2.2, you won't be far out. (It doesn't make much sense really to do this for very small lists of a few elements, though.)