# Java random insert collection

Tags: java, collections, insertion

I am considering using a Java collection that would work best with random insertions. I will be inserting a lot and only read the collection once at the end.

My desired functionality is adding an element at a specified index, anywhere between <0, current_length>. Which collection would be the most efficient to use?

Comment: Are the indices a contiguous range?

Comment: Java. The collection will grow and the indexes would be in range 0-length

Comment: @Bober02 What is length?

Comment: OK, I modified the question. I want to use some collection like ArrayList, which exposes add(Eleem, index) method, that would be most efficient on insertions. Thanks

Comment: What is your usecase? Is it possible to change algorithm to avoid random insertions e.g. by inserting sequentially and then shuffling once?

Comment: No, the values must be inserted at a specific place as I go along

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Useful link for your reference:
http://www.coderfriendly.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/java_collections_v2.pdf

Not entirely sure how you will be reading the information post input (and how important it is to you).  Hashmap or ArrayList would make sense depending on what you are looking to do.  Also not sure if you are looking for something thread safe or not.
Hope it helps.

Comment: what?? Random insertions into an ArrayList?

Comment: @unbeli - I may have misunderstood the question but I do not think that you understood it clearly as well.

Answer (score -2):

The inefficiency of using `List` is endemic to the problem. Every time you add something, every subsequent element will have to be re-indexed - as the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28int,%20E%29) states:

> Shifts the element currently at that position (if any) and any
>   subsequent elements to the right (adds one to their indices).

From your question/comments, it would appear that you have a bunch of `Object`s, and you're sorting them as you go. I'd suggest a more efficient solution to this problem would be to write a `Comparator` (or make your object implement `Comparable`), and then use `Collections.sort(list, comparator)` (or `Collections.sort(list)`).

You might suggest that your `Object`s are being sorted on the basis of other variables. In which case, you could create an extension of the `Object`, with those other variables as fields and extending `Comparable`, and with a method like `getOriginal()`. You add these wrapped objects to your list, sort, and then iterate through the list, adding the original objects (from `getOriginal()`) to a new list.

For info on the sorting algorithm of collections - see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753237/what-sort-does-java-collections-sortnodes-use)

Comment: List is an interface, it cannot be inefficienct. Inserting into LinkedList is O(1), but you need to find first. SkipList might help, but it's not in JRE.