# Quicksort or O(N.logN) sort in jdk

Tags: sorting, java, standard-library

**Is there a quicksort**, or another O(N.logN) sort, **available in the jdk standard library?**

`Collections` class doesn't bring hope:

> Implementors should feel free to substitute other algorithms, so long as the specification itself is adhered to. (For example, the algorithm used by sort does not have to be a mergesort, but it does have to be stable.)

and `Collections.sort()` gives no clue:

> **sort(List<T> list)**
>       Sorts the specified list into ascending order,according to the natural ordering of its elements.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753237/what-sort-does-java-collections-sortnodes-use

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau thanks for pointing that out, I remember reading about the Timsort but had forgotten about it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort, always impressive to see such innovations pop up in recent years (2002)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorting relies on [`Arrays.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29). As the sort method depends on the type, reading the JavaDoc is not so obvious.
A modified merge sort or a tuned quicksort depending on a threshold:

```
 /**
 * Tuning parameter: list size at or below which insertion sort will be
 * used in preference to mergesort or quicksort.
 */
private static final int INSERTIONSORT_THRESHOLD = 7;
```

Here is a post comparing quicksort and mergesort: [Quick Sort Vs Merge Sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680541/quick-sort-vs-merge-sort)

Conclusion: trust the Java implementation unless you really know what you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

`Collections.sort` is an optimized merge sort which actually guarantees O(n log n) in every case and it is stable; [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/algorithms/index.html) .